# What is exact definition of cycle?

Tags: graph-algorithm

The cycle definitions, which I have faced so far, say that there are nodes on the path v1, v2, ..., vk and if v1 and vk are same nodes, this path can be called `cycle`.

Does this mean that there is no cycle if first and last vertex are not same?

```
       A---C---T
      /   / \ /
     B---D   K
         |   |
         E---Z
```

A C T K C D

Is this a cycle?

Comment: Why can't you consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory))?

Comment: Apply your definition to the path you suggest. Now apply your definition to the part of that path that you *know* is a cycle. Where is the confusion?